# which texture should I connect to which input in BSDF

Tags: texturing, node-editor, 3d-view, shaders, transparency

I have a 3D bottle & 6 texture maps such as alpha.jpg, bump.jpg, color.jpg, color-blur.jpg, env.jpg & roughness.jpg .

So I want to mix my texture maps in the shader nodes of Blender To achieve the following result :
[image]

but I cant mix my maps into the blender correctly:
[image]

can you help me, which texture should I connect to which input in BSDF?

Comment: try to plug the bump into a the Height input of a Vector > Bump node, and plug this Bump into the Normal input of your Principled

Comment: env is world image? If yes, put that image into world nodes, not your object nodes

Comment: you can connect the alpha image to the *Alpha* slot of the *Principled BSDF*. Your setup is needed for the early 2.8x version of Blender when the *Principled BSDF* node had no *Alpha* slot. Check if the *Alpha* output of the image is the correct one (could also be *Color*, depends on the image).

Comment: Tip to help you out.  Enable Node Wrangler add-on if you haven't already.  In the shader editor, select only the Principled shader and type CTRL-SHIFT-T.  In the file open menu that pops up, select all of the image textures you want to use.  Blender will try to guess from the texture names what the best setup is.  Doesn't always work, because it relies on naming conventions, but even when it doesn't it's a good starting point.